# Getting selected item from listselect in vaadin with scaladin

Tags: scala, vaadin

```
val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("UserManager")

val users = DataServices.getUsers()


var userContainer = new IndexedContainer
userContainer.addContainerProperty("name", classOf[String],None)
userContainer.addContainerProperty("user", classOf[User], None)


val userList = new ListSelect { container = userContainer }

userList.itemCaptionMode_=(AbstractSelect.ItemCaptionMode.Property)
userList.itemCaptionPropertyId_=("name")

users.foreach(u=>{
    val item = userContainer.getItem(userContainer.addItem)
    item.getProperty("name").value = u.name
    item.getProperty("user").value = u
})

addComponent(userList)

val delButton = new Button { caption = "DeleteUser" }
delButton.enabled = false

addComponent(delButton)

userList.valueChangeListeners += (e => {
    val selItem = userList.getItem(e.property.value.get).getProperty("user")
    logger.info("{}",selItem)
})
```

the final logline gives me the correct value but I get WARNING:

> You are using toString() instead of getValue() to get the value for a
>   Property of type
>   com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer$IndexedContainerProperty. This
>   is strongly discouraged and only provided for backwards compatibility
>   with Vaadin 6

. To disable this warning message and retain the behavior, set the init parameter "`legacyPropertyToString`" to "`true`". To disable the legacy functionality, set "`legacyPropertyToString`" to `false`. (Note that your debugger might call `toString()` and trigger this message). To find out who is calling `toString()`, enable FINE level logging.

and I can't figure out what the correct way to get the selected item is using scaladin.

Using `vaadin 7.6.3` and `scaladin 3.1.0`

So what is the correct way to determine the selected item and not get the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Your way to get value

```
val selItem = userList.getItem(e.property.value.get).getProperty("user")
```

is correct. Problem is in implicit conversion to string inside

```
logger.info("{}",selItem)
```

Properly way is to get setItem.getValue() then check its type, convert to string and then call loger.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this:

```
val selItem = userList.getItem(e.property.value.get).getProperty("user").value.get.asInstanceOf[User]
logger.info("{}", selItem)
```

Which I think is essentially the same the answer posted.